# Ios app is not running on simulator and not even generating build

Tags: react-native

I am developing an app in react native, everything seems to be working until last week, but suddenly app is not running on ios simulator, or not creating ios build,

I have tried everything from lowering my react native version, or deleting files recommended in the terminal, or removing dependencies, but not thing worked, anyone has a solution to it?

```
this is my pod file code

    target 'voc' do

    # Pods for ReactNativeMaps
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'ReactNativeExceptionHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-exception-handler'

    pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
    pod 'yoga', path: "../node_modules/react- 
    native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga.podspec"
    pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-device-info'

end
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == "yoga"
      target.remove_from_project
    end
    if target.name == "react"
      target.remove_from_project
    end
  end
end

error at the moment, but it keeps changing after I do some solutions

Loading dependency graph, done.
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `PickerIOS` from `/Users/vikas/Desktop/VOCBakup/voc-mobile-app/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js`: Module `PickerIOS` does not exist in the Haste module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/vikas/Desktop/VOCBakup/voc-mobile-app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:161:1460)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/vikas/Desktop/VOCBakup/voc-mobile-app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:91:16)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/vikas/Desktop/VOCBakup/voc-mobile-app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:272:4579)
    at dependencies.map.relativePath (/Users/vikas/Desktop/VOCBakup/voc-mobile-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:376:19)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/vikas/Desktop/VOCBakup/voc-mobile-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:374:16)
    at /Users/vikas/Desktop/VOCBakup/voc-mobile-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:212:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/vikas/Desktop/VOCBakup/voc-mobile-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:297:313)
    at /Users/vikas/Desktop/VOCBakup/voc-mobile-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:297:473
```

Comment: have you tried cleaning the cache and build folder

Comment: Yes i already tried it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems an error about an upgrade of your react-native version. You may try to reset the cache as suggested [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19019) and to erase the cache of iOS simulator (Hardware > Erase all content and settings...)

Comment: just tried, but now i am having this error  error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65.

Comment: try to remove the ios/build folder and run it again